# Java webservice remove cdata from dom

Tags: java, xml, dom

My web service returns a String(xml) am building this string using DOM now the problem is when I want to convert this xml to String.  There is an extra CDATA that is being added initially and I can't seem to be able to remove it.
I got this beautiful function from stackoverflow but the problem as mentioned is that its adding the CDATA which i don't need since I want to return an Xml string. 
Please not that am using Soap web service.

```
    public static String doctoString(Document doc) {
    try {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
        return sw.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error converting to String", ex);
    }
}
```

full output:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getInvoppResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.com/">
         <return>
           <![CDATA[
              <users>
                 <user>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>sert</name>
                 </user>
              </users>
            ]]>
          </return>
      </ns2:getInvoppResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

body output needed:

```
           <return>           
             <users>
               <user>
                  <id>1</id>
                  <name>sert</name>
               </user>
             </users>             
           </return>
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the document to see what's being passed in. The code you've provided probably works fine. I suspect your document just happens to contain CDATA. By the way indent is unnecessary for a web service.

Comment: Why you think you don't need CDATA section?

Comment: What is the top level element in your `doc`? Is it return or users?

Comment: @user156873, the Cdata is breaking the xml when i want to read it from php...@Henry users is the top element, it looks like java adds return automatically... i think the problem isn't from the above but from the web service itself, it seems to be enforcing cdata on output xml... any idea how can i disable this feature that is breaking my code?

Comment: @rtp can you edit your question and add a full SOAP envelope? And, by the way, what library you're using to work with SOAP in php?

Comment: @user1516873 am using SoapClient on the php side, I edited the question

Comment: @rtp So, just do something like `$res = $client->getInvopp();` and you will get in $res string without CDATA, begins with <users> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a less elegant but functional Java solution (Updated for new XML in question):

```
p = Pattern.compile("\\A.*?(\\<users\\>.*\\<\\/users\\>).*?\\z", Pattern.DOTALL );
s = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
"   <soap:Body>\n" +
"     <ns2:getInvoppResponse xmlns:ns2=\"http://services.com/\">\n" +
"      <return>\n" +
"        <![CDATA[\n" +
"           <users>\n" +
"              <user>\n" +
"                 <id>1</id>\n" +
"                 <name>sert</name>\n" +
"              </user>\n" +
"           </users>\n" +
"         ]]>\n" +
"       </return>\n" +
"    </ns2:getInvoppResponse>\n" +
"    </soap:Body>\n" +
"</soap:Envelope>\n";

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches())
{
    s =m.group(1);
}
```